# How to display model data from the laravel controller into react component using inertiajs

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I how the model in my backend, laravel and I want to show all the records in the react as we usually do in blade file of laravel.
Below is what I have done.

```
class ClientController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $data=Client::all();
        return Inertia::render('Home',compact('data'));
    }
}`

in my react component I want to display it like this below:

function Table(){
    return (
        <div>
            <Table>
                <tr>
                    <td>name</td>
                    <td>email</td>
                    <td>address</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{}</td>
                    <td>{}</td>
                    <td>{}</td>
                </tr>
            </Table>
        </div>
    )
}

I just want a way to get access to the variable assigned to the model in the controller so i can        map the data into the table in the react page. If it is in laravel blade, it is easy for me.

    class ClientController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(){
            $data=Client::all();
            return Inertia::render('Home',compact('data'));
        }
    }

    in my react component I want to display it like this below:

    `function Table(){
        return (
            <div>

                <Table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>name</td>
                        <td>email</td>
                        <td>address</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{}</td>
                        <td>{}</td>
                        <td>{}</td>
                    </tr>
                </Table>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I just want a way to get access to the variable assigned to the model in the controller so i can map the data into the table in the react page. If it is in laravel blade, it is easy for me.`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Just that, I need the answer in the react component using inertiajs. For laravel blade, I don't have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your data in JSON format for rendering it on frontend:

```
return response()->json($data);
```

If you want to get an generated html:

```
return view('table', compact('data'));
```

Then create an Blade view file (`table.blade.php`) in `views` folder, and add something like (sorry, don't know what a structure of your `$data` collection):

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>email</td>
      <td>address</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach($data as $row)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $row->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->address }}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </table>
</div>
```

But in second case the response will be recognized as `text/html`, and you  additionally need to parse it. You can also put rendered html into JSON response:

```
$tableHtml = view('table', compact('data'))->render();
return response()->json(['html' => $tableHtml]);
```